# Can we rethrow exception using constructor if yes then why?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class A
{
    int a,b;
  public:
    A(int X,int Y)
    {
        X = a;
        Y = b;
        try
        {
            if (b == 0)
                throw b;
            else
                cout << a / b;
        }
        catch (int a)
        {
            cout << a; //throw;can we rethrow??then what is purpose of it??
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This code will not even compile.

Comment: ITYM `a = X; b = Y;`.

Comment: That was typing mistake bro.

Comment: `what is the purpose of it` is not very clear. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception in the constructor means something really bad happened, and since constructors can't return a (invalid) value to indicate failure in proper object construction, there are 3 options: to initialize the object in some special state in a hope that somewhere else in the caller code it'll be checked and handled properly, or to set an external variable/flag to mark the initialization failure, or to throw an exception after releasing any memory that it dynamically allocated. In general, if an exception is thrown before an object is fully constructed, destructors will be called for any member objects that have been constructed so far. And if an array of objects has been partially constructed when an exception occurs, only the destructors for the array’s constructed objects will be called. In addition, destructors are called for every automatic object constructed in a try block before an exception that occurred in that block is caught.

Comment: @RoseAhmed, you're most welcome. Consider voting up and accepting my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

"can we rethrow?" - Yes. You can always rethrow a caught exception, to let someone higher up in the call-stack also handle it (or have it terminate the program if not caught).